# context to handlebars is an object?

Tags: php, jquery, handlebars.js

I encoded the response from the database in json, getting a json with this structure that I sent with echo from a controller with json_encode ( I work in php):

```
[
{column1: value, column2: value...}            //row 1
{column1: value, column2: value...}            //row 2
....                                           //row n
]
```

My script (my template in handlebar) is:

```
<script id="handlebars_deals_list" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each data}}
        {{tittle}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

I passed the context in this way:

```
var source=jQuery('#handlebars_deals_list').html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context={data:response};//response is the json data I showed earlier
console.log(context); //Object{data="\n[{"id":"149417","biz_n......null,"index_deal":"0"}]"}
var html=template(context);
console.log(html); //empty!!?!?!?!!?!?!?!?!, why????
```

But I dont see any template rendered

Comment: It's solved, I posted the solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after fighting a little with this issue I had the solution:

```
function process_deals_date(response){
    var response=jQuery.parseJSON(response); //THIS IS THE KEY
    var source=jQuery('#my_template').html(); 
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    Var html=template(response);            
    console.log(html);      //RIGHT POPULATED THE TEMPLATE
```

}